# Error con el paquete eulerr

Tags: r

Estoy intentando realizar un diagrama de venn con la función euler. Para ello he ejecutado el ejemplo que aparece en la siguiente página:

https://www.analyticslane.com/2020/09/30/truco-r-creacion-de-diagramas-de-venn-en-r/

He ejecutado el siguiente código y me sale este error:

```
library(eulerr)
 library(Rcpp)


data <- c(uno=100,
       dos=220,
       tres=150,
       "uno&dos"=24,
       "uno&tres"=10,
       "dos&tres"=22)
venn <- euler(data)

Error in bit_index_cpp(n) : 
el paquete 'Rcpp_precious_remove' no ofrece la función 'Rcpp'
```

He intentado reinstalar el paquete Rcpp pero sigue saliendo el mismo error. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude reproducir tu problema, y entiendo que tienes un conflicto de versiones, `eulerr` está requiriendo funcionalidad que está en una versión más actual de `Rcpp`. Lo que puedes hacer es desinstalar los dos paquetes:

```
remove.packages("eulerr")
remove.packages("Rcpp")
```

Luego instalas solo `eulerr`:

```
install.packages("eulerr")
```

Que debería instalar la dependencia faltante de `Rcpp` en la versión más actual que se necesita. Eventualmente, podrías también instalar la versión de desarrollo más actual:

```
install.packages("Rcpp", repos = "https://rcppcore.github.io/drat")
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio, a partir de ahora cuando me de un problema así lo eliminaré y lo volveré a instalar. Funciona perfectamente, gracias